# authentication failures with external users

Tags: scmmanager

I am trying to have SCM Manager accept users from my organization so they can log in using their Windows username and password. I have installed the LDAP plugin, but it still doesn't recognize my own windows username and password from my organization

I don't really understand - I think I shouldn't even need LDAP and some kind of basic authentication should be able to figure out my username password on windows active directory etc type of thing...

Do I need the SSL to do this? It says various things about a binding problem.

I am using the custom LDAP profile. I put wsproxy in the proxy server area and enabled. I have no idea what that means but it was the same configuration that I saw in a previous installation of SCM-server that worked with organizational credentials on windows server.

This problem occurred after upgrading from version 1.6 to 2.9.
Though I was not the person who set it up on v1.6.

UPDATE: what's needed is not LDAP plugin, but rather understanding how to configure active directory for SCM - previously, in 1.X versions active directory plugin worked under the hood - now it needs to be configured and I have no idea how -- also the active directory plugin for 1.X is no longer available - if you could provide me with that code I might be able to see how it connects to AD and then go from there on version 2.X - any chance you can get me access to the code of  https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/active-directory-plugin??

Answer (score 1):

We have an issue for the LDAP plugin saying that the migration of the ldap password may fail (though I cannot reproduce this), so maybe this happened with your migration, too. Proxy settings should not play any part in this game, because as far as I know company ldaps aren't behind a proxy.

The configuration for 2.x should be the same as for 1.60. We haven't changed anything here. So first I would try to reenter the "Connection Password". If this still fails, please use the "Test connection" feature. Enter a valid authentication here. This tells you, on what level the connection fails and may show you an exception with further information.

Feel free to post your results here for further investigation.

Comment: Thanks. In the config for the old version i see an ldap authentication password which starts with {enc} which i think means some kind of encoding... not sure if I should just copy and paste that... doesn't seem to work that one... maybe i need the unencoded password or something

Comment: Hi Rene, the issue is that we were relying on the Active directory plugin but now it seems that plugin is no longer available and its not clear to me how to configure active directory